# Enter license key during desktop installation of Windows Mobile app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, installation

I've got a CAB file with the Windows Mobile application and the MSI package which installs that CAB on Windows Mobile Device (using a custom installer).

Now i'm trying to add ability to enter license key for that Windows Mobile app using desktop installation package.

I've added "Customer Information" dialog to MSI so i can enter the key. So what i need to do next is get that license key from my custom installer, do some validation, store that key n a file and copy the file to the mobile device into installation directory.

So, the questions are:

- How can i retrieve the license key i've entered during installation from my custom installer?
- How can i programmatically copy file created by custom installer to PDA into installation directory via active sync during installtion?

UPDATE:

I found a way to retrieve the info entered during installation using [MsiGetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130(VS.85).aspx) ([c# wrapper](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msi/MsiGetProductInfo.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Remote API (RAPI). This will provide you with the ability to create/write to files on the PDA from your desktop application or installer.

For a C# solution OpenNETCF's open source wrapper called [OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication](http://rapi.codeplex.com/) would be an excellent starting point.